# Group array of objects by unique pair of value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an issue with my array. I didn't find a similar case on the forum so I'm asking for help here.

Here is an example of what I got, and what I want in output.

input :

```
var array = 
  [
   {scanned_time : '2020-01-01 12:00:00',
   client : 11111,
   code : 'A11111'},

   {scanned_time : '2020-01-01 12:00:00',
   client : 11111,
   code : 'A22222'},

   {scanned_time : '2020-01-01 12:00:00',
   client : 22222,
   code : 'A33333'},

   {scanned_time : '2020-01-02 12:00:00',
   client : 11111,
   code : 'A4444'}
]
```

"scanned_time" and "client" are kind of unique pair.

The output I would need :

```
var result =
[
 ['2020-01-01 12:00:00', 11111, 'A11111', 'A22222'],
 ['2020-01-01 12:00:00', 22222, 'A33333'],
 ['2020-01-02 12:00:00', 11111, 'A44444']
]
```

I tried multiple things using map, reduce etc but I wasn't able to find anything, I'm not even close.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT :**

Starting point :

```
let result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.scanned_time] = r[a.scanned_time] || [];
        r[a.scanned_time].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
```

which give me

```
{
  '2020-10-26T13:33:00.000Z': [
    {
      AD_code: '852589',
      scanned_time: 2020-10-26T13:33:00.000Z,
      client_code: '12385'
    },
    {
      AD_code: '951478',
      scanned_time: 2020-10-26T13:33:00.000Z,
      client_code: '12385'
    }
  ],
  '2020-10-26T13:32:00.000Z': [
   {
      AD_code: '369874',
      scanned_time: 2020-10-26T13:32:00.000Z,
      client_code: '12385'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add the attempts you made as a starting point?

Comment: `var result = array.map(a => Object.values(a));`

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible code example. Without code, there isn't much anyone can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `for loop` to achieve this, I did some work around this. Try it out!

```js
var array = 
  [
   {scanned_time : '2020-01-01 12:00:00',
   client : 11111,
   code : 'A11111'},

   {scanned_time : '2020-01-01 12:00:00',
   client : 11111,
   code : 'A22222'},

   {scanned_time : '2020-01-01 12:00:00',
   client : 22222,
   code : 'A33333'},

   {scanned_time : '2020-01-02 12:00:00',
   client : 11111,
   code : 'A4444'}
]
const result = []
for(const obj of array) {
  const acc = result.find(c => c.includes(obj.scanned_time) && c.includes(obj.client))
  if (!acc) {
      result.push([obj.scanned_time.toString(), obj.client, obj.code])
  } else {
    acc.push(obj.code)
  }
}

console.log(result)
```